# How to convert reflect.Pointer() to []string when using pg.Array?

Tags: go, go-pg

I'm using go-pg to write a custom query cache system that takes a query arguments that are passed to Query function and generates a hash key that is used for Redis. I'm using Go's reflect to check the argument types which works, until I use pg.Array as a passed argument.

Reflect gives me reflect.Ptr, but how do I extract the pointer's struct/Array when the switch case block is called?

```
func GenerateQueryCacheKey(args ...interface{}) string {
    var argumentString = ""

    for _, arg := range args {

        v := reflect.ValueOf(arg)
        switch v.Kind() {
        case reflect.Array, reflect.Slice:
            ret := make([]interface{}, v.Len())

            for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
                ret[i] = v.Index(i).Interface()
            }

            GenerateQueryCacheKey(ret...)
        case reflect.Bool:
            argumentString += strconv.FormatBool(v.Bool())
        case reflect.String:
            argumentString += v.String()
        case reflect.Int:
            argumentString += string(v.Int())
        case reflect.Uint:
            argumentString += string(v.Uint())
        case reflect.Float32:
            argumentString += strconv.FormatFloat(v.Float(), 'E', -1, 32)
        case reflect.Invalid:
            log.Printf("Invalid type handle! " + fmt.Sprintf("%T", arg))
            argumentString += "nil"
        case reflect.Ptr:
            p := v.Elem()

            ret := make([]interface{}, p.Len())

            for i := 0; i < p.Len(); i++ {
                ret[i] = p.Index(i).Interface()
            }

            GenerateQueryCacheKey(ret...)
        default:
            log.Printf("Unhandled reflect type supplied! " + fmt.Sprintf("%T %T", arg, v))
            argumentString += "nil"
        }
    }

    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, argumentString)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```

pg.Array definition: https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/lib/pq/-/blob/array.go#L29:6

EDIT: The link posted has the incorrect definition of pg.Array. I accidentally grabbed the wrong library from sourcegraph.com.

Comment: *"how do I extract the pointer's struct/Array"* You are already doing `p := v.Elem()` to get the value to which the pointer points.. does that not work for you?

Comment: *"How to convert reflect.Pointer() to []string when using pg.Array?"* You can check if a reflect.Type is convertible to another. i.e. `v.Elem().Type().ConvertibleTo(reflect.TypeOf([]string{}))`. If you get `true` you can use https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert

Comment: ... or check directly against `pg`'s `StringArray` type. `v.Elem().Type() == reflect.TypeOf(pg.StringArray{})` and then use https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Convert

Comment: Much of the code can be replaced with fmt.Sprint(arg).  The return value from calls to GenerateQueryCacheKey is ignored and therefore not included in the hash.  The expression `string(v.Int())` does not do what you think it does

Comment: I've been running into more issues using reflect, and tried a different approach. Not sure if that's the best method, but it's doing the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reverting away from reflect and using the more direct approach.

I simply imported the types.Array from `pg` and created an interface{} slice and manually added the strings into the interface{} slice and used the spread operator to create a recursive function for the time being. Not sure if it's the best method, but it works for me at the moment.

```
func GenerateQueryCacheKey(args ...interface{}) string {
    var argumentString = ""

    for _, arg := range args {

        switch v := arg.(type) {
        case bool:
            argumentString += strconv.FormatBool(v)
        case string:
            argumentString += v
        case int:
            argumentString += strconv.Itoa(v)
        case uint64:
            argumentString += string(v)
        case float64:
            argumentString += strconv.FormatFloat(v, 'E', -1, 32)
        case *types.Array:
            stringArrayArgs := make([]interface{}, len(v.Value().([]string)))
            for i, vs := range v.Value().([]string) {
                stringArrayArgs[i] = vs
            }

            argumentString += GenerateQueryCacheKey(stringArrayArgs...)
        case nil:
        default:
            log.Printf("%T was requested and not handled!\n", v)
            argumentString += "nil"
        }
    }

    h := md5.New()
    io.WriteString(h, argumentString)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", h.Sum(nil))
}
```